# Delay SpringBoot application startup until db is up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-retry

I have a SpringBoot application that will fail to start up when the database it is using is not up since the datasource bean will fail to initialize. I want for my application to not start before my db is up in order to avoid this failure.

To mention that this app is running in Kubernetes so one option would be to use an init-container. I would want though to have that logic inside the application itself.

First of all, is that a bad idea and I should stick with init-containers?

If it is not a bad idea what is usually the best approach for this. I was looking at Spring Retry and one possible solution seems to be to have retry logic in the @Bean datasource initialization method. Does that have any possible drawbacks? Is there a better way?

Comment: Please check out this link https://deinum.biz/2020-06-30-Wait-for-database-startup/

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but there it seems that the datasource object needs to be created for it to work. My problem is that my datasource bean fails on creation because it needs to connect to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you but in case you have Data source beans declared.

You can you [@Lazy](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation) annotation to delay the bean initialization until required.

Your application startup shouldn't fail on startup as the Datasource bean would not be initialized until needed

Comment: Not a bad suggestion. But if the application starts up and gets requests before db is ready then I would still get an error.

Comment: Maybe a work around could be change the application logic to not initialize the datasource bean until Db is up. Although this statement seems to be a bit vaug though

Answer (score 0):

You can have a startup probe to check DB connections at the start. If you want the DB connections to be constantly pooled for health, you can use other [probles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-readiness-gate). Or in the pipeline which you use to deploy, after the check build unittest phases, you can add a step to check connections of external services/db which you use.